# Executing teradata stored procedure from SAS

Tags: sas, teradata

I'm trying to execute Teradata stored procedure from SAS ,but am failed to find the correct syntax,
here is example of what i tried:

libname tbconn teradata server="10.11.18.15" database="yy" user=x pw=xx;
execute tbconn.ProcedureName(date '2011-03-31');

and i also tried to use call command instead of excecute but it didnt work also.
any idea people.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
libname tbconn teradata server="10.11.18.15" database="yy" user=x pw=xx; call <databaseowner>.ProcedureName(date '2011-03-31');
```

Where `<databaseowner>` is the database where the stored procedure is located on Teradata. I'm not sure if `database="yy"` in your example is the same database where the stored procedure can be found or not.

**Edit:**
Does SQL that is passed-through to the database need to be wrapped in something like an EXECUTE function on SAS? `EXECUTE(call <db>.<procedure>(<param>);) BY tbconn;`

Comment: same error appear , it give an error msg which is is called "Error 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order" and i also tried connectionName.DatabaseName.procedureName